# Calling a custom method for form validation at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called `generate_form` which uses jQuery to create a form and insert it into the page.  Several other functions call this general one to create their form, and it in turn returns the form.

In order to do validation, i want the caller to be able to provide their own validation function as the specific use case has non-standard constraints (such as having to issue ajax calls to check/verify things).  The issue i'm running into, is i'm not sure how to get the custom validation function into the submit event of the form.

Very simplified and truncated code:

```
function user_test() {
  $('#formcontainer').append(generate_form(
    {
      name:'test',
      id:'user_test_form',
      fields:
        [
          {name:'username',type:'text',id:'username'}
        ],
      validation:function() { return $('#username').length > 0; }
    })
  );
}

function generate_form(data) {
  var form=$('<form>',{id:data['id']});
  //SNIP: add fields to form

  $(form).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //does not work, because data is undefined in this scope
    if ( !data['validation']() ) {
      //SNIP: validation failed notice
      return false;
    }

    //SNIP: post form

  });
  return form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways around this. One would be to bind the submission callback to the context of `data`, so:

```
$(form).on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.validation && !this.validation()) return false;
}.bind(data));
```

Another would be to pass `data` as event data. This is done via the third param of `.on()`:

```
$(form).on('submit', null, data, function(event) {//...
```

The original `data` is then accessible in the callback via `event.data`.

Also bear in mind you were assuming a validation callback was passed before calling it which, if there isn't one, will error.

Comment: The .bind(data) is what i was missing, worked like a charm, thanks!